# Background thread doing DB access hangs UI

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, oracle, user-interface

I've made a small utility program to test if a PC has a possibility to connect to a certain Oracle database.

To keep the UI responsive, and see the progress steps, I put the DB code in a background thread. To my amazement, the UI still hangs (but not as much).

It's really no big deal with this app, but I thought that the case is interesting in general, that the DB code in the thread hangs the UI thread!

```
    private void bgwDataAccess_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bgw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        try
        {
            bgw.ReportProgress(0, "Starting...\r\n");
            bgw.ReportProgress(0, "Active ConnectionString:\r\n");
            bgw.ReportProgress(0, Settings.Default.ConnctionString + "\r\n\r\n");

            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(Settings.Default.ConnctionString);
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM MYTABLE", con);


            bgw.ReportProgress(0, "Opening db...\r\n");
            con.Open();
            bgw.ReportProgress(0, "Opened.\r\n\r\n");

            bgw.ReportProgress(0, "Executing SQL-query...\r\n");
            Object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            bgw.ReportProgress(0, String.Format("Result: {0}\r\n\r\n", result.ToString()));

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void bgwDataAccess_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtResult.Text += e.UserState;           
    }
```

Comment: Little note which does not solve your problem, remove the catch and use try-finally to close the connection in any case in the finally. You should declare (but not open) the connection before the try block to be able to have the con object available also in the finally.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about that!

Comment: Can you define/describe "hangs the UI thread" ? How severe is this?

Comment: Why you are doing a BackgroundWorker bgw = sender as BackgroundWorker; and bgw.ReportProgress(0, "Starting...\r\n");? You can directly call bgwDataAccess.ReportProgress() right? Also use Using() instead of closing / disposing the connection explicitly

Comment: Are you sure that the BackgroundWorker is set to support reporting progress (WorkerReportsProgress)?

Comment: Anuraj: There are two overloads of ReportProgress, one which just takes an int (percent) and the one I'm using, since I'm sending text back.

Comment: Shayan: I've set the WorkerReportsProgress = true, other than that, I've not done anything special , I dont think there's a need for that.

Comment: Henk Holterman: It freezes completely for a couple of seconds. For at least one time. You cant move the windows, and it gets the white-faded.

Answer (score 1):

Do you access the Oracle namespace anywhere in your code before this? This is just a guess, but maybe that pause is your application loading the required .dlls

You could try pre-loading the module. I use something like the code below in my applications. First I display a splash screen to show the app is loading and then call the snippet below to load all of the required dlls. That way, once the app is loaded, there's no pauses further down the line.

```
void PreloadDLLs()
{
    Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::GetEntryAssembly();
    array<System::Reflection::AssemblyName^>^ referencedAssemblies = assembly->GetReferencedAssemblies();
    for each(System::Reflection::AssemblyName^ referencedAssemblyName in referencedAssemblies)
    {
        try
        {
            Assembly^ a = assembly->Load(referencedAssemblyName);
        }
        catch(System::Exception^ /*e*/)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Apologies for the C++/CLI syntax, but hopefully you can see how to convert that to C# - mine's a little rusty :-)

**[Edit]** I think this is pretty much C#:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

private void PreloadDLLs()
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    System.Reflection.AssemblyName[] referencedAssemblies = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
    foreach(System.Reflection.AssemblyName referencedAssemblyName in referencedAssemblies)
    {
        try
        {
            Assembly a = assembly.Load(referencedAssemblyName);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but it made no difference in this case. Although your suggestion is a nice trick that probably will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can change query to "SELECT  top 1 id FROM MYTABLE" and impact will be the same.

In case impact is not caused by those operations, you can use profiler to figure out which .net code causes impact.